# How to Generate Bearer Token From Kubeconfig File Programmatically On Outside of Kubernetes With Golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubeconfig

I am trying to create a cli tool for kubernetes. I need to generate Bearer Token for communicating with kubernetes API. How can I generate the token from Kubeconfig File? I do not want to use external library or kubectl.
Here is example Kubeconfig File:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://192.168.1.18:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: 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
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to generate Bearer Token for communicating with kubernetes API

You cannot ”generate” these tokens. They are *issued* by the control plane and signed with the *private key* that the control plane holds. It would be a security hole if you could generate these on the client side.

Comment: You are right. When i check kubeconfig files from cloud providers also they have tokens with users which created by internal components. I decided to use kubeclient libraries.